# confusing part to basic accounting question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Directions: Given the information find the weekly and monthly taxable wages (4.3 weeks per month).
This is for federal income taxes.

Weekly Taxable Wages: $\$21.40$ per hour, $40$ hours a week, $47$ weeks per year

Weekly Taxable wages: $\$21.40*40= \$856$

Monthly Taxable wages: ?

I really don't know what to do here. Do I just take $\$21.40*40 \text{hours}*4.3$ weeks?  I'm a bit confused here since they do give that this person works for $47$ weeks annually but i don't know what to do with it.  Oh monthly taxable wages are the amount of wages before being taxed.

Comment: The dollar sign is used to instruct the site to render $\LaTeX$.  If you want dollar signs, you need to precede them with backslashes.  That is why you are getting the italics, as the dollar signs have to come in pairs.

Comment: There is a [finance stackexchange site](http://money.stackexchange.com/) where dollar signs don't escape into $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 1):

I would do that, multiply by 4.3 weeks/month.  It ignores the statement of working 47 weeks per year.  Maybe you only consider that when figuring an annual salary, or maybe you are supposed to average that in (even for weekly wages?) by multiplying by $\frac {47}{52}$

Comment: Maybe you are right. I should average it in